# Should I put a Google sign in button on every page?

Tags: javascript, php, session, google-signin

I have built a quite simple site that users sign in to with a Google sign in button on the index page. After verifying the token etc, a PHP session is created, carrying the Google user id from page to page in order to identify the user.

I also wrote a bit of code (with the intention of including it in most pages) that will display the Google sign-in button, verify the token again and exit to index.php if the Google-generated user id doesn't match the one that is being carried by the PHP session. I'm not sure if this is necessary, but I thought it might improve security a little in case it were possible to spoof the session user id.

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.

  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  var userid = <? echo $userid; ?>;

  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=" + id_token, function( data ) {       
        if (data.sub != userid)
        {
            window.location = 'index.php'; // If the Google log-in doesn't match $userid, redirects to index
        }
    }, "json" );                                                                

}

</script>
```

Is this necessary, or should I just have the sign-in button on the front page and rely on the session user id from then on?

I suppose I could have an issue if a user bookmarks a page, but in this case maybe I would be better off having some sort of check for if the session has been created and redirecting if not?

Comment: You can create a session variable as soon as you get the user data from the Google API and check for that session variable on pages only registered users can access. No need to run the script on every page if the Google API returns OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SESSION['LoggedIn']` or something similiar.

LoggedInCheck.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();

 if($_SESSION['LoggedIn']==FALSE){
     session_destroy();
     header("Location: /login.php");
     die;
 }

 else{}
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented this with a slight variation, using !isset($_SESSION['userid'] to check if any value had been set for the userid that's carried by the session.

Comment: @rob also add `session_destroy();` if no value set right before the redirect to get rid of any user data that might be stored in session cookies